# pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file (continuation of the problem)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have recently started using Mac for coding. Thus, I had to move all my files from my previous computer (Windows). Long story short, everything was good until this error occurred.

`pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file`

I checked Stackoverflow and found this question with the explanation of how to resolve the problem. [How to uninstall pygame on mac OSX 10.9.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120883/how-to-uninstall-pygame-on-mac-osx-10-9-4)

But still nothing.
I use python3, however, python 2.7 was installed on my computer initially (Idk how) and I checked so that my program does not notice it.
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

did you check your PIP version if not check it and if it needs to be updated u can update

than u can reinstall PyGame library

Every PC system has Python old version. In order to use Python u have to Update your Python up 3.5 version.. than hope everything will be fine :)

Comment: I use commands "pip3 uninstall pygame" and  "pip3 install pygame" to complete your second suggestion

Comment: And I have python 3.8 installed